# azure devops: running unit tests in parallel

Tags: azure-devops, nunit, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have more than 20 assemblies for which we need to run Unit-Tests by bucketing them in 2 groups which run on 2 different VMS. Both VMs are independent of each other and run in parallel. But, The tests within the VM run sequentially and take a long time to finish(we have a lot of UTs).
Something like this:

```
- job: UnitTests1
timeoutInMinutes: 50
pool:
  vmImage: $(hostedPool)
steps:
  - template: ./templates/run-unittests.yml
    parameters:
      artifactName: $(buildArtifact)
      testAssemblies: ['assembly1', 'assembly2', 'assembly3', 'assembly4', 'assembly5', 'assembly6', 'assembly7', 'assembly8', 'assembly9', 'assembly10']
      runName: UnitTest1

- job: UnitTests2
timeoutInMinutes: 35
pool:
  vmImage: $(hostedPool)
steps:
  - template: ./templates/run-unittests.yml
    parameters:
      artifactName: $(buildArtifact)
      testAssemblies: ['assembly11', 'assembly12', 'assembly13', 'assembly14', 'assembly15', 'assembly16', 'assembly17', 'assembly18', 'assembly19', 'assembly20']
      runName: unitTest2
```

`run-unittests.yml`

```
- ${{ each testAssembly in parameters.testAssemblies }}:
- task: VSTest@2
displayName: 'UT: ${{ testAssembly }}'
inputs:
  vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
  testAssemblyVer2: |
    $(Pipeline.Workspace)\${{ parameters.artifactName }}\**\MyProject.${{ testAssembly }}.Tests.dll
  runSettingsFile: build/default.runsettings
  runInParallel: false                                       
  runOnlyImpactedTests: false                                 # Test Impact Analysis was evaluated and returns incorrect results
  codeCoverageEnabled: true                                   # collect code coverage
  platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

`default.runsettings` for test

```
<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
<RunConfiguration>
<MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
<ParallelizeAssemblies>false</ParallelizeAssemblies>
<ParallelizeTestCollections>false</ParallelizeTestCollections>
```

How can I start multiple threads/processes to run these UTs in parallel with in 1 VM. `runInParallel` doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Can you show `./templates/run-unittests.yml`?

Comment: I added more details. The flag runInParallel doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: Your VM have more than one core?  You are restricting parallelism in the run.settings file?

Comment: @Matt, The agents offered to us by Azure Devops.  We don't own them; Azure DevOps makes them available for us to use.  AFAIK we can't update the number of cores on the machine since we don't own them, but I would think they would be multi-core machines.

Answer (score 1):

`runInParallel` argument means running tests in parallel on multi-core machines. If set, tests will run in parallel leveraging available cores of the machine. This will override the MaxCpuCount if specified in your runsettings file. Click [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/parallel-test-execution/) to learn more about how tests are run in parallel. So you need to check whether you VM is multi-core, and check whether you have specified MaxCpuCount in your runsettings file.

You can also refer to the following documentation to use Visual Studio Test (VSTest) task to run tests in parallel across multiple agents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#massively-parallel-testing-by-combining-parallel-pipeline-jobs-with-parallel-test-execution

Comment: I dont see `MaxCpuCount` settings. Our VMs have 2 cores. I have updated the details above with `default.runsettings`. Nevertheless, as you said `runInParallel` should have over-ridden `MaxCpuCount`.

Comment: Do you select the agent running on the VM? If you run the tests directly on the VM, how's the result?

Comment: Dong, not sure what you mean by select agents on the VM, how and where can I check that? As far as I know we don't specifically select agents. Also not sure what you mean by run texts directly on the VM. I think that's what we are doing. I feel this could be the problem testAssemblyVer2: |
    $(Pipeline.Workspace)\${{ parameters.artifactName }}\**\MyProject.${{ testAssembly }}.Tests.dll. we are passing Test dlls in a for loop 1 by 1, may be we need to pass all of them in one shot?

Comment: Which agent pool do you use? Is the test running on the VM machine? You may have a try to pass all test dlls in one shot to see the result.

Comment: we are using the azure dev-ops provided agent pool.

Comment: If you use microsoft-hosted agent, then the tests will run on the hosted agent machines. You need to deploy agents on your VM, and use this self-hosted agent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: I tried providing dlls as a list to `testAssemblyVer2` and couldn't get that to work. currently we output the dlls in a directory and divide them in 3 sets and to process with 3 agents in parallel. 1 agent processing 1 dll at a time  in a for loop as shown in `run-unittests.yml`. Not sure what about the right way to provide multiple dlls with exact names to replace `testAssemblyVer2: |
    ${{ parameters.artifactName }}\**\MyProject.${{ testAssembly }}.Tests.dll` into `testAssemblyVer2: |
    ${{ parameters.artifactName }}\**\MyProject.Project1.Tests.dll,\**\MyProject.Project2.Tests.dll`

Comment: As you mentioned you used microsoft-hosted agent, the tests would run on the hosted agent machines. If you want to run tests on your VMs, you need to deploy agents on your VM, and use the self-hosted agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops. Have you deployed the self-hosted agents? You may share your entire log to see whether there is more details.

Comment: we do not want to use self-hosted agents. As mentioned earlier the problem seems to be with `testAssemblyVer2` where we pass dlls one by one. we need to pass them as a list.

Comment: `testAssemblyVer2` supports multiple lines of minimatch patterns. For example: `testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\MyProject.Project1.Tests.dll
     **\MyProject.Project2.Tests.dll
     **\MyProject.Project3.Tests.dll`

Comment: Is that a new line character that separates minimatch patterns?  if yes, I can try out converting this to a yaml format with `- ${{ each testAssembly in parameters.testAssemblies }}:`

Comment: Yes, it's a new line character separates minimatch patterns.